# Remove Empty Horizontal Space between columns (Reactstrap, Bootrap, React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I have a good feeling this is a gap in my knowledge in CSS-grid, bootstrap, ect, but I've been having a bit of trouble with trying to reduce the white space between this row of columns I've rendered out based on user data.

Below I've included a screenshot and some HTML of what it currently looks like. My only goal currently is to try and reduce some of the space between each row. I've already tried the no-gutters bootstrap class, making changes to the outer row as well as the columns themselves, using justify or align classes and nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="mt-2 ml-2 no-gutters m-0 d-flex row row-cols-6 row-cols-sm-6 row-cols-md-6 row-cols-lg-6 row-cols-xl-6">
   <div class="mb-4 no-gutters d-flex col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="presenters-card-profile ml-2">
         <div>
            <div class="presenters-card-profile_initials-container ml-2"><span class="presenters-card-profile_initials">BB</span></div>
         </div>
         <div style="word-break: break-word; padding-top: 10px;">
            <p class="presenters-card-profile_name-text m-0">USER FULL NAME</p>
            <p class="presenters-card-profile_occupation-text m-0"> </p>
            <a class="presenters-card-profile_link-text text-primary m-0" href="#">See profile</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   // Repeat of same column below for x data points 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `mb-4` ( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/ ) has a purpose of margins, Is that what's in your way ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus the mb-4 class serves as a bit of spacing between the columns vertically, my issue is with the horizontal spacing more. All take more of a look at the documentation though thank you :)

Comment: You can try 
1. to reduce `<div class="mb-4 no-gutters d-flex col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">` to `<div class="mb-4 no-gutters d-flex col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">` but it will bring 4 cards in row.
2. to remove `ml-2` from `<div class="presenters-card-profile ml-2">`

Also if you could provide a code snippet or code sandbox it will help in debugging and and helping.